# "Радио" or "ра́дио"

Tags: правописание, существительные, лексикон

I was wondering which is the correct form. радио or ра́дио ? I mean I've seen people writing both of them. And I've also seen many letters with this accent above the a. Is it necessary? Which spelling is correct?

Comment: We don't usually write words with a stress mark in everyday life. It's usually done in dictionaries and textbooks for learners.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both forms are correct.

The "accent" is a stress mark.  Stress marks are omitted in most books. They are printed in books for beginner readers, and in words where a change of stress would change the meaning.

Comment: So it isn't an error when I write радио, right?

Comment: @shader301202 No, it's not.  It's exactly how everyone writes it, outside of dictionaries and textbooks.

Comment: @shader301202 one small exception is ё letter. 1) it is never written with the stress mark, for it is always stressed if present (at least in non-foreign words). 2) many people, maybe majority, skip those dots and write ё as e instead

Comment: @Vitaly ...or when incorrect/unusual stressing was used and that specifics has to be written down, like if writing some gorbachevisms or remote village dialect, etc

Comment: @Arioch "1) it is never written with the stress mark:" Sometimes it is! https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%91%D1%80%D1%91%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%85

Comment: @Arioch "it is always stressed if present" - except for the word ёфика́ция :)

Comment: Oh, guys, come on, then half of Mongol-origin words would be there too, like Йороол-гуй. Let's stay within Russian vocabualry :-)